# C# JSON How to serialize a list with the class name as a node name

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I want to serialize a list with the class name as the parent name of the child elements being serialized in the following format:

```
"parent": [
   "title": "",
   "child_items" : [
      "child_item" : {
         "field1": "1",
         "field2": "2"
       },
      "child item" : {
         "field1": "1",
         "field2": "2"
      }
   ]
]
```

I have a class called Parent and I have class called ChildItem.  I have a property on the parent class that is a list of ChildItems as well as the title property.

When I serialize this using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject I get the following:

```
"parent": [
   "title": "",
   "child_items" : [
      {
         "field1": "1",
         "field2": "2"
       },
      {
         "field1": "1",
         "field2": "2"
      }
   ]
]
```

If I create a separate class called ChildItems that has a property that is a list of ChildItem and make the ChildItems class a property of Parent then I get the following:

```
"parent": [
   "title": "",
   "child_items" : {
      "child_item" : [
         {
            "field1": "1",
            "field2": "2"
         },
         {
            "field1": "1",
            "field2": "2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want the output to show child_items as a list of child_item with child fields underneath each one.

EDIT:
Here is an example I created: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ozJK9B.  I want to have "ChildItem" to show up as the list of items under "ChildItems" and have the ChildItem properties to show up underneath each ChildItem.

Comment: If you want type information, you could use [TypeNameHandling setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) but the output will be different from what you requested.

Comment: can you add a snippet of your classes and what output you want?

Comment: Here is an example I created: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ozJK9B.  I want to have "ChildItem" to show up as the list of items under "ChildItems" and have the ChildItem properties to show up underneath each ChildItem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps explain why you would like to alter the serialization rather be content that the serialization reflects your class structure. Do you need to reflect such structure to be compliant with a service expecting such data structure?

If you need to comply with a json structure, like a data contract, then perhaps take a look at one of the son parsers that will generate the class that reflects a json dataset

https://json2csharp.com/ would be one that you could use

Comment: Nice tool.  Thanks.  I was trying to make my output conform to the expected format for importing an order into Salesforce using JSON.

Comment: @user1408767, I figured as much, just be aware that the parsers are making a class for everything so do not blindly take what they offer. also, pay attention to JsonProperty("Name") annotation as it allows you to use what would otherwise be illegal property names and helps avoid having a mess when you obfuscate code as it doesn't map the property name but the attribute. You can then map thinks like "First-Name" to FirstName

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do.  The parent had to have a property of a list of child items.  The child item class would have one property which is the child item details.
Here is an example I wrote:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgz7CV